# Android same tab bar for all activities

Tags: android, tabactivity

well, I have my Android app that have 4 main options. For that I created a TabActivity with this options.

Problem, when I enter to one of this, a activity is called. Cool. Imagine I have a list and when I click on one row I open other activity, the tab will disappear what is correct. But I want this tabBar always.

how can I achieve this?
if I copy/page this tab in every activity I need it it will load the ones that are attached to the tab and wont show the one that I opened before, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with FragmentActivity. There is a addTab function to add tabs to action bar, in which you set tabs. With fragments and action bar what you want to do is possible

Take a look at [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) that includes actionbar compatibiliy with tabs and more for non Honeycomb versions of Android.

Comment: i would like to know if there is other approach for this. Just want to simulate root tab bar of iOS (some android fans may not like it but im doing the same app for both :D)